# Kafka: Reading off __consumer_offsets with node-rdkafka

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka

Is there a way to decode the data in the topic __consumer_offsets using javascript?

Right now I have something like:

```
consumer.on('data: ', function(data) {
  if(data.value) {
    console.log('data.value', data.value.toString())
  }
})
```

and prints stuff like
data.value: consumerrange,rdkafka-78bfd5c4-2a48-4573-ae6b-5f5957332b0b,rdkafka-78bfd5c4-2a48-4573-ae6b-5f5957332b0brdkafka/192.168.7.190u0u0__consumer_offsets�__consumer_offsets2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like `node-rdkafka` (or `kafka-node` for that matter) include the necessary message formatter, so short of writing it yourself, probably not directly.

Your best bet is likely to simply read it from the command-line in a `child_process`.

The command to run looks like this:

```
kafka-console-consumer --consumer.config /tmp/consumer.config \
  --formatter "kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter" \
  --zookeeper localhost:2181 \
  --topic __consumer_offsets
```

Which can be spawned as a child process would look something like this:

```
import { spawn } from 'child_process';

const child = spawn('kafka-console-consumer', ['--formatter "kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter"', '--zookeeper', 'localhost:2181', '--topic', '__consumer_offsets'], { stdio: 'pipe' });

// create a handleData and handleError function
child.stdout.on('data', handleData);
child.stderr.on('data', handleError);
```

Short of writing your own message formatter to convert the binary messages from that topic, this is probably going to be your easiest route.

Here is more information on reading Kafka consumer offsets: https://www.ctheu.com/2017/08/07/looking-at-kafka-s-consumers-offsets/#consuming-consumer-offsets

Comment: I have seen this kind of answer, I am asking if it is possible to do it in javascript. I saw the Burrow code and they do it, but could not understand why they convert it to big endian or any of the other things they do, mainly because I could not find anything about the format of the binary data or the endianness.

Comment: I know. And I answered your question. It isn't possible in JavaScript directly unless you either write the formatter yourself or pull it in as I mentioned.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I will add the green check mark. Do you know why am I getting this exception when I try the console version? Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager$OffsetsMessageFormatter

Comment: Hmm.. not sure. Could be you have an older version of Kafka, or that article was written for an older version of Kafka. It could also just be a simple case of escaping. Try to add or remove the `\` from before the `$`

Comment: @GuillermoBlanco you need kafka.coordinator.group for newer versions of kafka

Comment: In newer versions of this it looks like `--zookeeper` is gone, but `--bootstrap-server` is now required